# Making a different table in latex

Tags: tables

How can I make something like this?

[image]

I know how to make a table but I don't know how to make that line between 3 and 5 in a table. Can someone please explain me how to do it??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `\multicolumn{'num_cols'}{'alignment'}{'contents'}`.

Code to generate your table:

```
 \begin{tabular}{|c | c| c| c| c |c |}\hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{0}&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{3}&\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{6}\\\hline
3&5&3&5&3&5\\\hline
 \end{tabular}
```